# How to align multiple rows after right brace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, braces

I want my text, which I wrote after right brace, to be aligned right next to the brace. But they keep going far right and align with the longest line's end, vertically.

```
  \begin{align*}
    \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            x=ab\\
            y=ab\\
            z=ab\\
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    \begin{aligned}
        something in 1st row\\
        something in 2nd row which is super long and causes some\\
        something in 3rd row\\
        something in 4th row\\
        something in 5th row
    \end{aligned} 
    \end{align*}
```

[image: I need these rows to be aligned right next to the brace]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You need to insert ampersands before text in the second `aligned` (and also before equal signs in the first one, if you like to have expression there aligned at them) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
    \left.
        \begin{aligned}
            x & =ab\\
            y & =ab\\
            z & =ab\\
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    \begin{aligned}
        &   something in 1st row\\
        &   something in 2nd row which is super long and causes some\\
        &   something in 3rd row\\
        &   something in 4th row\\
        &   something in 5th row
    \end{aligned}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I was pretty sure missing something essential and fairly easy (not that experienced in Latex as you can see). Appreciated for the effort.

Comment: @nope, you are  welcome! with time your (La)TeX skills will improve! Happy (La)TeXing!